# Operator gets lost when a expression is sent as argument Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JS function

```
    let a = 0.33, c=13.89;
    var res = calcRound(c*2+calcRound(a*2,1,1),1,1);
    console.log(res);

    function calcRound(value, figure, padding) {
    let val = value;
    let result = parseFloat(val);
    result = result.toFixed(figure);
    return result;
   }
```

It returns a 27.8. But the answer should be 28.5
I have debugged the code. At first, it calculates this and it is correct

```
calcRound(a*2,1,1) = 0.7
```

Second time the '+' operator between `c*2` and `calcRound(a*2,1,1)` gets lost.
it becomes like this `27.780.7` which should be like this `27.78+0.7`
I know JS first evaluates the expression before sending it as an argument. My question is why the '+' operator is getting omitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is the concatenator operator in JS, it thinks the result from calcRound() is a string and behaves accordingly.

As mentioned by Andy in the comments, you can see in the
[documentation for toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

> Return value: A *string* representing the given number using fixed-point
> notation.

Change the return of your function to (to make sure it returns a number):

```
return Number( result );
```

```js
    let a = 0.33,
      c = 13.89;
    var res = calcRound(c * 2 + calcRound(a * 2, 1, 1), 1, 1);
    console.log(res);

    function calcRound(value, figure, padding) {
      let val = value;
      let result = parseFloat(val);
      result = result.toFixed(figure);
      return Number(result);
    }
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that it's [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) that's coercing the float to a string in case that's not clear to the OP.

Comment: Aahh!! Thank you so much for noticing this. It is the main reason that causing the expression to convert into a String.

Answer (score 0):

It's not getting omitted, JavaScript is treating them like strings and adding 27.78+0.7 as strings, you want to surround them in `Number()` or `parseFloat()` statements so that they are treated as numbers.

Like so:

```
calcRound(parseFloat(c*2) + parseFloat(calcRound(a*2,1,1)),1,1)
```

Comment: Should NOT use `parseInt()`, since the values are NOT integers. Maybe `parseFloat()` instead.